# android multiple lines per button with custom style for each line

Tags: android, xml, styles

The title says it all. I am aware that you can use the following methods to add more than one line to a button. However I want to know how to set a different style to each line. How can I do that via XML and also if possible dynamically via Java.

```
android:text="Hi&#10;Hello"
<string name="multilines">Line1Line1\nLine2Line2</string>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach a LinearLayout with vertical orientation to the button and put different TextViews in it.
It might be a little longer but it gives you full control on it and you can do it both via xml and Java. Answer me if you need an example.

Comment: Awesome, I am going to try it and get back to you. I was using LinearLayout as the button originally in xml but now I need the buttons to be added dynamically.